# How to perform an action on currency select event in magento?

Tags: magento

I have a currency select option in the header and I want to display a message if a user selects the US Dollar. I dont know how to read this event. 
I am fairly new to magento and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make changes in file `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\controllers\CurrencyController.php`

Change in function

```
 public function switchAction()
        {
            if ($curency = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('currency')) {

             // add message   
             if($curency=="USD")
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("your message"); 

                Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($curency);
            }
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        }
```

Comment: Could you also help me with another question please. My website automatically displays the product prices in a currency that is according to the geographical location (through IP address). I need to disable the US Dollar prices for US customers and make GBP as the default currency for both UK and US customers.